# France Visa application form online error

Tags: visas, schengen, france, online-resources

I have created my account online on France Visa website for form filling. But now I am unable to access my account as the website isn't able to load properly. Every time I log in, the page will take more time to appear and then when it does it will end up with error page: "504 Gateway time out. the server didn't respond  in time".

Please let me know what to do next, and if we can apply for Schengen visa manually then how to book the appointment at the centre?

Comment: That's an issue with the actual website, their server is not responding. Their tech support people will need to address it; if they're aware of it, likely the best option is to just wait it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about website tech support, not travel.